# Things becomes invisible if it extends Canvas limit area, want to scroll inside canvas area to make invisible things visible

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to have a scroll kind of something which will visible such parts those exceeds canvas limit and becomes invisible.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,60);
ctx.fillStyle="#FFD000";
ctx.fillRect(150,0,50,100);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In my code; a red rectangle and a yellow rectangle are present. If I could have my canvas area with less width like  " width="150" " ; not 200 ;then the yellow box hides.

I want to keep myCanvas width as 150 ; not 200 (as mentioned in code) and want to see the yellow box(with scrolling the canvas or whatever possible way). Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit a larger canvas into a smaller area, you can:

- Wrap the larger canvas in a div,
- Size the div with CSS to your desired proportions,
- Set the div's overflow property to scroll

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6RPGr/

[image]

**Html**

```
  <h4>Use scrollbars to view more of the canvas</h4>
  <div id="canvasWrapper">
      <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=100></canvas>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
  #canvasWrapper{ overflow:scroll; width:150px; height:100px; border:2px solid blue; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,60);
ctx.fillStyle="#FFD000";
ctx.fillRect(150,0,50,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.I don't want the width as 200. If I give 200 width then for sure yellow box will be visible. I want width to be 150 and scroll horizontal to view the yellow box. In this way if I add some new color boxes in the canvas, I don't need to resize the original canvas size each time. By scrolling I can able to see the new items even though those are more than canvas original limit.

This refine code is not working as my above expectation,

```
<html>

<head>  
<style>
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
#canvasWrapper{ overflow:scroll; width:150px; height:100px; border:2px solid blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvasWrapper">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>
</div>
<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,60);
ctx.fillStyle="#FFD000";
ctx.fillRect(150,0,50,100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer does what you ask...The canvas has scrollbars so you can scroll past the red rectangle and see the yellow rectangle.